# AWS GLUE SQL join with single row from right table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Im trying to join two datasets in AWS glue

Table 1(alias af):

| id | data | created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string 1 | 2020-02-10 |
| 2 | string 2 | 2020-02-11 |
| 3 | string 3 | 2020-02-12 |

Table 2 (alias mp):

| id | data | data2 | created | foreign_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string 1 | json string | 2020-02-10 | 2 |
| 2 | string 2 | json string | 2020-02-11 | 3 |
| 3 | string 3 | json string | 2020-02-12 | 3 |

What i want to do is get all rows from table 1 and select the first row from table 2 that matches the foreign key.

This is what I have currently after going through a few questions i found that i need to wrap the query with an aggregate function to let spark know that only 1 element will match this subquery.

```
select af.id,af.data
       (select first(mp.data)
        from mp
        where af.id= mp.foreign_key
       ) as alias1,
       
       (select first(mp.data2)
        from mp
        where af.id= mp.foreign_key
       ) as alias2
from af 
having alias 1 is not null and alias2 is not null
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
ParseException: mismatched input 'first' expecting {')', ',', '-'}(line 3, pos 15)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are e better off joining the two tables with a left outer and then and using row_number. This query syntax seems off, especially with the use of ‘having’ after the ‘from’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution that works for my use case. Comment above was right the SQL was funky before.

```
Select af.*, mp.*
from af  join
     (select mp.*, row_number() over (partition by mp.fid order by mp.created_at) as seqnum
      from mp
     ) mp
     on af.id= mp.fid and seqnum = 1;
```